# C#: How to send key combination in selenium's Keyboard.SendKeys

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm using Selenium 2 on Windows to automate firefox. I tried to send 'Alt+Esc' to the browser to minimise it on start. However firefox keeps typing the '{%ESC}' in its address bar. What should I do? thanks.

```
using (driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxProfile))
{
    driver.Keyboard.SendKeys("{%ESC}");
}
```

Comment: have you tried a google search [Send Keys C# Selenium](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=c%23%20c%23%3a%20how%20to%20send%20key%20combination%20in%20selenium's%20keyboard.sendkeys)

Comment: I did, but only found some java examples which use methods not available in C#. I ended up using `System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("%{ESC}");`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I use this to open a new window (with the keyboard input) and it works just fine

```
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();                          
Actions action = new Actions(driver);
action.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Control + "n").Build().Perform();
```

Answer (score 4):

I prefer:

```
element.SendKeys(Keys.Control + "a");
```

Now you can focus on the element and not only on the webdriver

Answer (score 1):

Sending regular key use `SendKeys("ab12#$")`.
Sending a modifier key (Keys.Shift, Keys.Control, or Keys.Alt) use

```
.[KeyUp\keyDown]([OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Control\OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Alt...])
```

And you can combine them as needed:

```
action.KeyDown(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Shift).SendKeys("ThisWillBePrintedCAPS").KeyUp(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Shift).SendKeys("ThisWillBePrintedRegular").Build().Perform();
```