# What is the alternative to java Keys.chord() method in C#?

Tags: c#, selenium, textbox

I am new to C# & not able to delete some textbox content using Selenium Clear command. In such situation I was trying the below command when I was working in Java.

```
webelement.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL,"a", Keys.DELETE));
```

Now in C#, the chord command is not available.

I have gone through the Keys class please find the link https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Keys.html and believe chord is not there for C#. Do we have any alternative to perform the same operation. I am able to delete the inputs from textbox using JavaScript but how can I achieve pressing many keys at once in C#.

Currently using this approach using JavaScript

```
    public static void clearTextboxContentUsingJS(IWebDriver driver, IWebElement element)
    {
        ((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].value ='';", element);
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35127108/how-to-set-value-to-input-web-element-using-selenium/35127217#35127217

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C#: How to send key combination in selenium's Keyboard.SendKeys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26855809/c-how-to-send-key-combination-in-seleniums-keyboard-sendkeys)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could try pressing `Keys.Backspace` in a loop and see if that helps.

```
var length = element.GetAttribute("value").Length;

for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    webElement.SendKeys(Keys.Backspace);
    Thread.Sleep(100);
}
```

Also, I know you have tried `Keys.CONTROL` + `"a"` + `Keys.DELETE`. I have tried this solution in the past, but split onto separate lines, so that may be worth trying as well:

```
webElement.SendKeys(Keys.Control + "a");
webElement.SendKeys(Keys.Delete);
```